# Traefik Error use of closed network connection

Tags: sockets, tcp, udp, traefik

I have problem with TCP, UDP EntryPoints

```
time="2022-08-03T10:12:16Z" level=error msg="accept tcp [::]:3478: use of closed network connection" entryPointName=tcp3478
time="2022-08-03T10:12:16Z" level=error msg="Error while starting server: accept tcp [::]:3478: use of closed network connection" entryPointName=tcp3478
time="2022-08-03T10:12:16Z" level=error msg="accept tcp [::]:80: use of closed network connection" entryPointName=http
time="2022-08-03T10:12:16Z" level=error msg="Error while starting server: accept tcp [::]:80: use of closed network connection" entryPointName=http
time="2022-08-03T10:12:16Z" level=error msg="accept tcp [::]:443: use of closed network connection" entryPointName=https
time="2022-08-03T10:12:16Z" level=error msg="Error while starting server: accept tcp [::]:443: use of closed network connection" entryPointName=https
time="2022-08-03T10:12:16Z" level=error msg="accept tcp [::]:57772: use of closed network connection" entryPointName=tcp57772
time="2022-08-03T10:12:16Z" level=error msg="Error while starting server: accept tcp [::]:57772: use of closed network connection" entryPointName=tcp57772
```

my Traefik.yaml:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQ2dU.png)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your YAML as **text** rather than as a screenshot. On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why. For instructions on formatting see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*. A [mcve] showing code that reproduces the problem would maximize your chances of getting help. See [ask].

Answer (score 1):

This did not solve it for me: https://community.traefik.io/t/2-3-errors-on-container-start-is-this-someting-to-worry-about/8438/8

I assumed this was a startup error (because it says `Error while starting server`) but then I noticed it only occurred when I stopped the docker container. So I currently ignore it because everything works fine. Unfortunately I was not able to create a minimal reproducible example, otherwise I would have filed a bug report.

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered this issue and the root cause was the readiness and liveness probes checking /ping on the traefik port. Basically what the error message means is, that those listening sockets have been externally closed, in my case due to the pod being terminated because it did not become ready.

The actual root cause was related to this: https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/getting-started/configuration-overview/#the-static-configuration

where the most important point is, that mixing cli and yaml configuration will not work, as yaml will always supersede the command line flags

Hope this helps.